# Space (and pipe sign) works on occasion only

Tags: keyboard, pipe

I have an issue that when I try to write pipe sign "|" and space after that, I sometimes get wrong type of space (\240) and my command fails.
This issue persists on different shells.

How could I fix this?

I am using Finnish keyboard layout.

```
timo@timo-i7-ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep ruby
timo      7169  2633  0 12:12 pts/2    00:00:00 ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/rails new admin4
timo      8736 26515  0 14:22 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ruby
timo@timo-i7-ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep ruby
No command ' grep' found, did you mean:
 Command 'igrep' from package 'openimageio-tools' (universe)
 Command 'dgrep' from package 'debian-goodies' (main)
 Command 'rgrep' from package 'grep' (main)
 Command 'zgrep' from package 'gzip' (main)
 Command 'zgrep' from package 'zutils' (universe)
 Command 'sgrep' from package 'sgrep' (universe)
 Command 'lgrep' from package 'lv' (universe)
 Command 'egrep' from package 'grep' (main)
 Command 'ngrep' from package 'ngrep' (universe)
 Command 'grep' from package 'grep' (main)
 Command 'agrep' from package 'agrep' (multiverse)
 Command 'pgrep' from package 'procps' (main)
 Command 'xgrep' from package 'xgrep' (universe)
 Command 'vgrep' from package 'atfs' (universe)
 Command 'fgrep' from package 'grep' (main)
 grep: command not found

timo@timo-i7-ubuntu:~$ cat pipecom
ps -ef | grep rails
timo@timo-i7-ubuntu:~$ cat pipecom2
ps -ef | grep rails
timo@timo-i7-ubuntu:~$ ./pipecom
timo      7169  2633  0 12:12 pts/2    00:00:00 ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/rails new admin4
timo      8777  8775  0 14:26 pts/4    00:00:00 grep rails
timo@timo-i7-ubuntu:~$ ./pipecom2
./pipecom2: line 1: $'\302\240grep': command not found
timo@timo-i7-ubuntu:~$ diff -w pipecom pipecom2
1c1
< ps -ef | grep rails
---
> ps -ef | grep rails
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this link on a french site: http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=65282 Now my french is bad but this link is also referred to on the Arch Linux forum (and that one is in english). This is probably the reason for your error too:

> With some keyboard layouts, type [AltGr] + product space character
>   that appears as a space but is not interpreted as such by the shell.
>
> What's happening is that by typing the |, you stayed pressing the
>   [AltGr] typing space. So, bash looks for the command [space] grep,
>   which does not exist.
>
> Retries typing, paying attention, or copy and paste, it should pass.
>
> If your problem is well there, you should be able to adjust your
>   keyboard to prevent it. (System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layout)

and

> I figured it out.  Shift+ on my keyboard produces a
>   nobreakspace.  When I type '| ' quickly I sometimes don't release the
>   shift key fast enough after typing '|' and so instead of typing an
>   ordinary space after '|' I'm typing a nobreakspace.
>
> Anonymous_user, thanks.  Your post was the clue I needed to start
>   thinking in the right direction.
>
> Jay

[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116321)

Comment: Probably the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999712/after-a-pipe-the-command-is-considered-prefixed-with-a-space. I had the issue on a French keyboard.